# Aggregate columns not in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In T-SQL (SQL Server 2008 R2, if it's relevant), what's the cleanest way to write the following query?

```
select dfd.ListName as ProvName, COUNT(distinct pv.PatientProfileId)
    from PatientVisit pv
        join DoctorFacility dfd on pv.DoctorId = dfd.DoctorFacilityId
    group by pv.DoctorId
```

I can think of a couple of different ways to do it. Realistically, I could probably just group by dfd.ListName instead, but I'm just paranoid enough to worry about hiring two John Smiths. :-) I know another option would be

```
select dfd.ListName as ProvName, DistPatCount 
    from (
        select pv.DoctorId, COUNT(distinct pv.PatientProfileId) as DistPatCount
            from PatientVisit pv
            group by pv.DoctorId
        ) pvc 
        join DoctorFacility dfd on pvc.DoctorId = dfd.DoctorFacilityId
```

but "butt-ugly" is the politest way I can think of to describe that. :-) Besides, I figured someone would know something I was missing...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the cleanest way to handle it would be to create a view of your patient count.  I find it difficult to believe this is the only place it would be helpful.

Alternatively, you could define a CTE (which is basically an inline view) containing this information:

```
WITH Patient_Count (SELECT doctorId, COUNT(DISTINCT patientProfileId) as patientCount
                    FROM PatientVisit
                    GROUP BY doctorId)

SELECT a.listName as provName, b.patientCount
FROM DoctorFacility as a
JOIN Patient_Count as b
ON b.doctorId = a.doctorFacilityId
```

(although, is `doctorId` really equal to `doctorFacilityId`?  That seems to be saying "yeah, that doctor, he's actually a *building*".)

Comment: +1 : Aggregating by IDs and then additionally joining to get Names and other Meta-Data is normally the cleanest in my opinion.  Only if the Meta-Data is already in the tables needed for the aggregation would I look at MAX(name), etc.

Answer (score 1):

If SQL were a little more clever you could do the following, because you know there can only be one facility for a given doctor.

```
select pv.DoctorId, dfd.ListName as ProvName, COUNT(distinct pv.PatientProfileId)
    from PatientVisit pv
        join DoctorFacility dfd on pv.DoctorId = dfd.DoctorFacilityId
    group by pv.DoctorId
```

Unfortunately, the single-value rule in SQL is too strict, and it prevents you from doing that.  The single-value rule is that *any* column in the select-list must be either in the GROUP BY clause or else in an aggregate function, regardless of the fact that it's not actually ambiguous in a case like the above.

So we can write the following to comply with SQL, even though it's logically not necessary to put ListName in an aggregate function:

```
select pv.DoctorId, MAX(dfd.ListName) as ProvName, COUNT(distinct pv.PatientProfileId)
    from PatientVisit pv
        join DoctorFacility dfd on pv.DoctorId = dfd.DoctorFacilityId
    group by pv.DoctorId
```

I'm assuming pv.DoctorId is a foreign key referencing dfd.DoctorFacilityId, not the other way around.

Comment: I think he doesn't want to return the `DoctorID` though.

Comment: Then just remove it from the start of the query, but leave it in the GROUP BY

Comment: Depends on the RDBMS implementation.  IIRC, some brands of SQL database don't like it if you GROUP BY a column that doesn't appear in the select-list.  I'm not sure if SQL Server is one of these.

Comment: SQL Server is in the "strict" camp. MySQL is "make something up". Postgres is better I believe because it deals with functional dependencies...