# expression not in aggregate or GROUP BY columns

Tags: javascript, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table that contains the following columns:
ProductID, ProductName, Price, CategoryID.

The goal is to print all the details (ProductID, ProductName, Price, and Category) about the most expensive product.

I executed the following query:

```
str = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName, MAX(Price) AS MaxPrice, CategoryID FROM Products;";
```

However, the exception mentioned in the title appears, and I do not find a reason for the exception appearance. I searched for explanations on the following links:

- [Expression not in aggregate or GROUP BY columns Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557485/expression-not-in-aggregate-or-group-by-columns-exception)
- [Aggregate columns not in group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299140/aggregate-columns-not-in-group-by)

I have also read and practiced in [SQL Lesson 10: Queries with aggregates (Pt. 1)](https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_with_aggregates)
According to my checking in SQLBolt, the way I wrote the query is acceptable.

After reading and practicing, I still do not understand why I need to use the GROUP BY here. It's not that I need to present the maximum price of each group...

Thank you very much beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is only an `ORDER BY` clause like:

```sql
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, Price AS MaxPrice, CategoryID 
FROM Products
ORDER BY Price DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

`LIMIT 1` will make sure that you fetch only the first row.

You got the error because when aggregating (i.e. sum, avg, max, min, count) a numeric column you need to tell SQL how you want to group the data by using the `GROUP BY` clause. For example if you wanted to find the Maximum price for each ProductName you'll have to use `GROUP BY` on `ProductName`:

```sql
SELECT ProductName, MAX(Price) AS MaxPrice FROM Products GROUP BY ProductName
```

[Group by (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_by_(SQL))

#### why is `GROUP BY` needed?

This is easier to understand with `sum()` than `max()` because for SQL both are aggregation functions. So let's say if you want to get the sum total of `Price` instead of maximum of price, so you would do:

```sql
SELECT SUM(Price) AS Total FROM Products --will give the total of all the prices
```

but if you added non-aggregated columns:

```sql
SELECT ProductName, SUM(Price) AS Total FROM Products --will not work
```

you will immediately see that this is not possible because there will be multiple product names, which one should be displayed for the sum of prices?. That's why it throws the error asking to use a `group by` clause.

hope this helps!

Comment: Some SQL based databases use LIMIT while others use TOP. you'll just have to find the equivalent of it in the SQL that you're using.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The requirement is to use one of the aggregate functions (like MAX). If I use ORDER BY and LIMIT then it seems like workaround.  I have studied from SQLBolt that it is allowed to do as I did, without using the GROUP BY. If I use the GROUP BY with ProductName as you wrote, then it doesn't answer the basic requirement - "...print all the details (ProductID, ProductName, Price, and Category) about the most expensive product."

Comment: @Modern please share the URL where you read that, and tell which database you're using?. Because I checked and found that your query will work in SQLite but throws an error in MySQL. read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11073406/7940996

Comment: Thanks again for replying. I'm using Access (Microsoft Access Database).

Comment: according to this answer stackoverflow.com/a/11073406/7940996 : *"use of an aggregate like Max requires a Group By clause if there are any non-aggregated columns in the select list"*.  So you can do 
`SELECT MIN(Price) AS SmallestPrice FROM Products;` but if you add "non-aggregated columns" you will need a `group by` clause

Comment: @Modern I have added an explanation to why aggregation functions need a `GROUP BY` clause when non-aggregated columns are also selected.

Comment: @Manlik I truly thank you for your help. I read the new part you added to your answer. The example is good, but it's still raising questions. When you discuss the SUM aggregate function, then it's obvious why you do need to use GROUP BY, however, MAX is a bit different than SUM, since you know that in one of the records there is the maximum price. In contrast to SUM - no record will keep the value of the sum.

Comment: @Modern, I think you could be right in fact in SQLite your query will work as you expected. i think this is a design problem, maybe `SUM()` and `MAX()`/`MIN()` should not be treated in the same category. As in the case of `MAX()` we can return other columns without necessarily adding them to `GROUP BY`. it reminds me of Zen Of Python: **Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.** they followed the first part but missed the second one!

Comment: Thanks again for replying. The problem is that I have to work with Access (Microsoft Access Database). That means, that I have to use the GROUP BY as you mentioned, although I do not find much logic in doing this. Another option is to make a subquery `str = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName, Price AS MaxPrice, CategoryID FROM Products WHERE Price = (SELECT MAX(Price) FROM Products);";` 
It works, but again, it's not what I desired to have.